# Trying to restore from 17 word seed

Tags: blockchain.info, client, electrum, seed, mnemonic-seed

I just found a seed for my very first wallet ever, I thought was long gone. Problem is my hand writing was shit at the time...(still is lol)

I have tried to restore in using this block chain tool:
https://blockchain.info/wallet/forgot-password?guid=

Now it gives me the error:
     Unknown Word frieghtner or vincitore

but that is definitely what was given. does anyone know of a list of all the words so I can spell check my hand writing?

I don't remember if this wallet was created with electrum or blockchain.info, but I think there is a small amount of etc from 6+ years ago. any help would be amazing... if we can get it I WILL tip.

thank you

Comment: 17 words seed and 6+years ago, it can't be Electrum, since "extended seed with custom words" was not implemented back then.
[Here is blockchain's legacy mnemonic phrase wordlist, scroll to the bottom of the page](https://github.com/blockchain/My-Wallet/blob/master/mnemonic.js). I couldn't find any words similar to frieghtner or vincitore.
Maybe it was a brain wallet passphrase?
Have you tried https://www.bitaddress.org offline and see if you get anywhere?

Comment: However I found the word ['vincitore' in a BIP39 Italian wordlist](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/italian.txt).....hmmm it just keep getting weirder.

Comment: It's a blockchain.info wallet, so it's not a 'seed', it's an encoding of your password.

Comment: When you decode you will get back your plaintext password